# Validating a login using PHP

Tags: php, session, curl

*This is definitely a duplicate of my previous question.
Once I understood what was going on, I tried editing my original question but it wouldn't save.  I tried logging out and logging back in, but I couldn't update it, so I made a new question with the more detailed info.*

The user in this scenario has to login to my application using the following link for our company's SSO:

```
https://example.com/signin.jsp?%20realm=auth&gotoURL=http://example.com/myURL/
```

After signing in here, they are redirected back to my website.

I'm trying to make something in PHP to determine whether or not the user has logged in, and my initial thought was to use cURL/PHP.

I can check whether or not they are logged in to our SSO using the same `example.com` website, here:

```
http://example.com/isTokenValid?
```

If this is true, they continue, if not, they get redirected back to the login page.

When I type `http://example.com/isTokenValid?` into the browser, I see either:

`boolean=true`

or

`boolean=false`

I don't know how to get PHP to recognize these outputs though.  I tried the following:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://example.com/isTokenValid?');
$answer = curl_exec($ch);
```

I'm confused by the response though.

Whether or not I'm logged in, If I execute JUST this code, I see

```
boolean=false
```

(although I don't know where this is coming from since I have no `echo` in this code..)

However, if I execute this code along with `var_dump($answer);` I see

```
boolean=false
bool(true)
```

What am I doing wrong with my code? Is it my PHP?  my cURL? Am I going about this all wrong? All i want to do is read this boolean value to determine whether or not the login took place successfully.  Do I need to use a session somewhere?

Comment: When you access http://example.com/isTokenValid?, what token is that site validating? I.e., I imagine you'd need to pass that value to the server in order for it to check whether it's validated.

Comment: I have no idea.... I don't know how I would pass that value since I don't ever get it.  The user logs in via our company SSO, which i don't have access to.  Is there a difference between me executing this cURL request and me typing the URL into the browser window?  Because it works in one but not the other... that's what I don't understand.

Comment: I would assume it's storing a $_SESSION variable that defines your token, and checks that token to determine TRUE or FALSE. Without access to that SSO server, I don't think there's any way for you to get that $_SESSION variable unless there's an API or something that's designed to play nice with other servers.

Comment: According to the very light documentation I have from my company: ", there will be a cookie created in the browser. To validate the session you can call the below REST urls with the cookie provided by our server: `http://example.com/isTokenValid?`

Comment: Aha! So then, you need to pass the cookie along with the request for the example.com/isTokenValid? page.

Comment: I don't know how to pass that specific cookie along.  In the past, I've used multiple cURL statements in a single page - one for authentication to a server where I use cURL's cookiejar to store a cookie, then keep the session open, but in this instance, I didn't do the original logic with cURL, so I don't know how to get the cookie.

Comment: Ok, I figured that part out using `print_r($_COOKIE)`.  I have a cookie called `[validate]` - not sure how to pass that successfully using cURL. I set up $validationCookie, then used `curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "validate=$validationCookie);` but I still get the same error as before.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know too much about using cURL via PHP. I would either 1) edit your post to reflect what we've talked about in these comments, or 2) create a brand new question addressing this new issue.